# Angular 8 Testing with Karma and Jasmine NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[api -> api]: NullInjectorError: No provider for api

Tags: angular, api, testing, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

**Karma error messages:**

[image: Karma error messages]

**app.component.spec.ts file code:**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing'
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'dalivalidb'`, () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('dalivalidb');
  });

  it('should render title', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('dalivalidb app is running!');
  });
});
```

I'm new to testing I'm trying to run my first automated test with Karma and Jasmine provided by Angular.
I've tried running the test but encountered 3 out of 3 fails regarding an API. Unfortunately I didn't find any relevant information about how to handle such error and I'm not expter in API too. So if anyone had encountered any simmilar issues or knows a fix it would be appreciated!!

I`ve tried multiple things including adding imports to the `app.component.spec.ts`

```
imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule
         ],
```

**You can check the website on [dalivalidb.netlify.app](https://dalivalidb.netlify.app/)**

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a dependency on `api` in `app.component.ts`.

Something like this:

```
constructor(private api: api, ...) {}
```

You have to provide a mock for `api`.

Try this:

```
let api: api;
describe('AppComponent', () => 
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    let mockApi = {}; // mock your API as a plain JavaScript object
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: api, useValue: mockApi } // provide the mock like so.
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

Show the full `app.component.ts` and I think I can help you a bit more.